# Task Scheduler user name not valid – removes domain/computer name upon saving task

Tags: windows-10, task-scheduler

After saving a task (in Task Scheduler) with the computer name/account,
I go to run the task and it does nothing (simply supposed to open an .exe). 
When I go back into the task properties, it shows it cut off the computer name from the user account. If I hit okay to save it and then type in the password of the local account, it says the account is not valid and won't allow me to save.

I am on a domain, but it appears to do the same thing for domain accounts. 
Any ideas what might be causing this?

NOTE: in the below images the "Run whether user is logged on or not" should be selected to emulate the issue:

Before saving task – account under security option includes computer name

[image: Before saving task - account under security option includes computer name]

After saving task and re-opening – account does not include computer name and am no longer able to save due to "account not being valid"

[image: After saving task and re-opening - account does not include computer name and am no longer able to save due to "account not being valid"]

Answer (score 1):

the same happened to me but when i used the full name (with computer name) used in "Author" so in your case:
IT-DESKTOP\*user
(write it manually) it worked fine

Comment: Please clarify what the use should type or ‘write’.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I guess that means, click on `change user group` write the name, then click on `check name` then `ok`. In my case, task scheduler skip the computer name unless I ask it to do so (if not the task doesn't work). I wonder if there is a way to change that faulty default setting.